# Expectation for probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

Today, I had posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912822/payoff-of-a-dice-game) question about the "Payoff of a dice game" and in the answers, most had explained by associating the problem with the concept of the expected value of a probability distribution. So, I caught up on that but I find that I'm still confused.

With regard to the *probability distribution curve*, I fully understand the reason why the sum of product of the random variable and the probability gives the expected value for a given experiment. However, I wish to obtain a deeper and more *intuitive* understanding of this concept. I watched Sal Khan's videos and he explained it by using the following example:

"Imagine that you are playing basketball. The probability that you will make a basket is 40%. If you throw $n$ baskets, the expected value is given by $np$, where $p$ is the probability of success, defined here as the event of making a basket. Think of it this way; for every basket that you throw, the ball is falling 40% into the hoop."

Although this is a clever way to think about this, I was wondering if anybody else had any more insights. How do you make sense of this concept in your head? Please share for it would help me tremendously.

**Edit**: I realize that I have not been very clear while stating the question and want to clarify that I understand the logic behind the other question that I had posted. The reason that I posted *this* question separately is because I wanted to know how other people made sense of these concepts of averages and expectation values inside their head. What is the most useful way to think about these concepts?

Thanks ever so much :) Regards.

Comment: Suppose 6 people have the following weights (in pounds):  150, 180, 115, 200, 180, 190.  What is the average weight?  Can you give an expression for this?

Comment: I would approach this problem by adding the weight of each person and dividing the total by the number of people taken into account(Which, in this case, comes out to be 169.1667). I get what you're trying to say but to be fully honest, I have never really understood the core principle behind averages either. Sorry.

Comment: Indeed it is  $\approx 169.1667$. So indeed you can write that average two ways: $$\frac{150+180+115+200 + 180+190}{6} = \frac{1}{6}150+\frac{2}{6}180+\frac{1}{6}115+\frac{1}{6}200+\frac{1}{6}190$$
You can think of "1/6" as the probability of being 150, "2/6" as the probability of being 180, and so on.

Comment: Note that "expected value" and "average" are synonyms.  If you randomly pick a person, equally likely over all 6, the "expected" weight of the person you pick is the same as the above average, which is $\approx 169.1667$.  That is because you pick a weight of 150 with probability $1/6$, you pick a weight of 180 with probability $2/6$, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You have said in the comments that you don't quite grasp the idea behind averages, so I'll try to respond to that.

The average is good for making guesses about large sets of data. If there were 2000 people in a hall and you wanted to know how much do they weigh together, you could either visit them one by one, asking them to tell their weight, and sum the numbers up. (That looks pretty tedious.) Or, you may ask only 100 of them and take the *average* of their weights. Then, you multiply it by 2000 to get your guess. So, if you add up weights of 2000 people, there's a good chance that the results will be quite similar to the case where every of them has the average weight.

However, it would be a mistake to draw any significant connections between the average and the weight of any single person. Let's say that the average is 80 kg. In the group of 2000, there may be little children weighing 20 kg, very fat persons weighing 150 kg, and most of the people anywhere in between. It can easily be more likely that you encounter people whose weight isn't anything near to 80 kg. But, if you come up to a group of 10, there is a good chance their total weight will be around 800 kg.

The expectancy of a random value follows the same idea. For a six-sided die, the expected value to show up is 3.5. If you roll 1000 times, you can be pretty confident that the sum will be somewhere around 3500. (If you want to have this formulated more precisely, it may be worth to look up some info on normal distribution.) But the 3.5 figure doesn't tell anything about result of a single roll. That may still be anything from 1 to 6.

And that's the logic behind the "expected payoff of -1/6" of your die game in the previous question. It doesn't say that if you play one round, you lose 1/6 of a coin. It only says that if you play, say, 1200 rounds, the results will be quite similar to the case when you lose 1/6 of a coin each round, in other words, you can count with losing 200 coins. Nothing less, nothing more. So if somebody offers you 1200 rounds of this game, it's not worth accepting, but if you play 10 rounds, the results may be various and you may even very well win.

Hope that will be helpful, and that others will bear with my not-very-mathematical approach.

Comment: Thanks so much :) After finding the average of the weights of 100 people, why should I multiply this number by 2000 and how does the logic behind this work?

Comment: Taking a 100 people from 2000 is a "sample" from the population. The sample mean is usually close to the population mean. That is why, we can assume that if we had asked all the 2000 people and find the average, we would have got almost the same answer. Now, we want the total age of the population and hence we multiply the sample mean by 2000.

Comment: Exactly. You just hope that there will be a similar relative number of people in all the weight categories in your sample of 100 as it is in 2000. (For instance, if you had 20 skinny, 50 normal and 30 fat people in that 100, you hope there will be roughly 400 skinny, 1000 normal and 600 fat in the 2000.) And this is why it won't work so well if you take a too small sample (there's a danger of bias: if you take, for instance,  only 5 people, they can be easily all skinny or all fat and that doesn't match the real distribution of weights at all.)

Comment: So I must multiply not the average weight obtained but the *probability* by the total number of people, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Assume a random variable $X$ that denotes the number of heads when you toss two coins together. $X$ has three possible values; $0, 1, 2.$
The probability of getting a $0$ (that is, no heads) is the probability of getting tails on one coin and getting a tails on the second coin. This is $0.25$.

The probability of getting $X$ as $1$ is the probability of getting a heads on the first coin, and the probability of getting a tails on the second coin, OR, vice versa (tails on first coin, heads on the second coin). This is $0.25+0.25=0.5$.

Similarly, the probability of $X$ assuming the value $2$ is when you get $2$ heads (that is, $0.25$).

Now you ask yourself, "what result should I expect when I toss two coins, one after the other? Am I most likely to get two tails, two heads, or one head and one tail?"

To answer this, you multiply each value of $X$ with its corresponding probability. Why do we do this? Well, let's look at the definition of probability. Probability can be defined as the frequency of an event happening, divided by the sum of the frequencies of all events happening. That is $$\frac{frequency\ of\ event\ A}{sum\ of\ frequencies\ of\ events\  A,\ B,\ C...}$$

The sum of all frequencies happens to be the entire sample space. Now let's look at the definition of the "mean". If we are given a frequency table with values A, B and C and their corresponding frequencies (freqA, freqB, freqC), the mean is 
$$\frac{(A)(freqA)+(B)(freqB)+(C)(freqC)}{freqA +freqB +freqC}$$ or 
$$\frac{(A)(freqA)}{freqA +freqB +freqC}+\frac{(B)(freqB)}{freqA +freqB +freqC}+\frac{(B)(freqB)}{freqA +freqB +freqC}$$
This is nothing but $$(A)(ProbA)+(B)(ProbB)+(C)(ProbC)$$ (where ProbA is the probability of A).

So we see that the mean value (or expectation value) is defined as above.

In the case of my example, the expected value is 1. This means that if I toss 2 coins a very large number of times (in an unbiased way), the most common outcome would be 1 heads and 1 tails, (not necessarily in that order). Calculating the mean or "expectation" value before hand means that I can safely predict that for a large set of two-coin-tossing, I will get 1 heads and 1 tails on average.

Comment: I don't understand why we have defined the mean like that. Can you please explain? Exactly what is the use of even defining the mean value of an experiment?

Comment: The mean is simply the average. It is defined like that so we can find out the average value of a set of data. Assume a set of people's weights: 65, 66, 65,67,67. The mean would be $\frac{(2)(65)+(66)+(67)(2)}{(2+1+2)}$ The value 2 is multiplied into 65 because that is how many times 65 occurs in the data.

Comment: For probability, when we calculate this "mean value" it simply means that we are trying to find, on average, what would be the most likely outcomes. That is, if we repeat the experiment a very large number of times, say 1000, the mean value that we calculated will predict that on average, outcome X is most likely to occur. This will be true if the experiment is unbiased and we calculated the mean properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand the question. Are you asking an intuitive explanation of why expectation of sum of random variables is the sum of expectations? We can break down the game into 6 different events,
$A_i$ is the event "The dice value is $i$". Now we define the paying rule.
$X$ is a function which gives value to each event. Intuitively $X$ is the game manager and he takes or gives you money based on the outcome of the dice. In the table you already have defined $X$,
$$X(A_i)=M_i$$

Expectation can be seen as a weighted sum of the values of a random variable, where the weights are the probabilities and the summands are the values of the the random variable.
If your expectation is negative that means that you will lose money in the average case, and if it's positive you will win money on the average case.
As if you asking what will the game manager give you at the end of the game. Hope it helped you.

Comment: Well, yes, I was asking for an intuitive way to think about the concept of expected value. Thanks :)